# SOAP::Lite - clients using version 1.1 and 1.2 threaded in mod_perl

Tags: multithreading, perl, soap, mod-perl, soaplite

I have several SOAP::Lite clients running under mod_perl in Apache hhtpd. 
Some of them use 1.1 soap-servers and some of them use 1.2 servers. So I have code like:

```
# In client 1:
my $soap1 = SOAP::Lite->soapversion("1.1");
$result1 = $soap1->method1();

# In client 2:
my $soap2 = SOAP::Lite->soapversion("1.2");
$result2 = $soap2->method2();
```

This works in stand-alone clients, but when I run the code under mod_perl, I seem to get stung by that the `soapversion`
 method has side-effects:

```
# From SOAP::Lite.pm 
sub soapversion {
    my $self = shift;
    my $version = shift or return $SOAP::Constants::SOAP_VERSION;

    ($version) = grep {
        $SOAP::Constants::SOAP_VERSIONS{$_}->{NS_ENV} eq $version
        } keys %SOAP::Constants::SOAP_VERSIONS
            unless exists $SOAP::Constants::SOAP_VERSIONS{$version};

    die qq!$SOAP::Constants::WRONG_VERSION Supported versions:\n@{[
        join "\n", map {"  $_ ($SOAP::Constants::SOAP_VERSIONS{$_}->{NS_ENV})"} keys %SOAP::Constants::SOAP_VERSIONS
        ]}\n!
        unless defined($version) && defined(my $def = $SOAP::Constants::SOAP_VERSIONS{$version});

    foreach (keys %$def) {
        eval "\$SOAP::Constants::$_ = '$SOAP::Constants::SOAP_VERSIONS{$version}->{$_}'";
    }

    $SOAP::Constants::SOAP_VERSION = $version;

    return $self;
}
```

This is what I believe happens:

Basically, the `soapversion` call rededefines essential constants in `$SOAP::Constants`. And since this is mod_perl, the `$SOAP::Constants` are global and shared between every server-thread (I believe. Please correct me if I'm wrong). This leads to a race-condition: Most of the times, the codelines gets executed more-or-less in the sequence seen above. But once in at while (actually about 2% of the calls) the execution sequence is:

```
Thread1: my $soap1 = SOAP::Lite->soapversion("1.1");
Thread2: my $soap2 = SOAP::Lite->soapversion("1.2");
Thread1: $result1 = $soap1->method1();
Thread2: $result2 = $soap2->method2();
```

And so, the `$soap1->method1()` gets called with `$SOAP::Constants` set as befitting version 1.2 - causing several namespace to be wrong, notably:

```
xmlns:soapenc="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-encoding"
```

Which is wrong for 1.1 - who prefers:

```
xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"
```

If I could somehow make `$SOAP::Constants` localized to a serverthread or something like that, I guess things would be fine. But any solution will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run Apache with the prefork model instead of the threading model (`mpm_prefork_module` instead of `mpm_event_module` or `mpm_worker_module`), so that each Apache child will have its own Perl interpreter, hence its own set of constants.

Otherwise have a look on the modperl documentation regarding the `PerlOptions` directive, specifically the `clone` and/or `parent` value. But stop using threads seem simpler to me, threads and Perl were never friends.

Comment: Unfortunately I am not in a position to test it, but it looks good to me.